# Why defaults read can't read some domains?And why is there an plist that stores all my information?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina

`defaults read` will output all domain contents and `defaults domains` will output all domain names.
However, I found that when I manually specify some domains`defaults read com.valvesoftware.steam.helper`, I get an error that domain does not exist but the file is there. E.g:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.valvesoftware.steam.helper
~/LibraryL/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.ImageSizingPresets
~/LibraryL/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.ViewState
~/LibraryL/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.bookmarks
~/LibraryL/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PreviewLegacySignaturesConversion
```

Two files in same folder but only one of them get an error.

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.plist 
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.securebookmarks.plist
```

And why is there an plist that stores all my information  even my keyboard model.
`co.twopeople.mate.plist` contains even more information than `Apple Global Domain`

Answer (score 2):

> Why defaults read can't read some domains?

It returns an unintuitive message for when a domain is blank.  For example, a fresh install of Firefox may create `/Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist`, however when trying to read this file:

```bsh
defaults read /Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist

# errors with:
# Domain /Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist does not exist
```

If you convert the `.plist` to xml you can see it exists but it's blank...

```bsh
sudo plutil -convert xml1 /Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist
cat /Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist
```

... shows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

So this message is simply misleading for blank `.plist` files.  Note, a similar misleading message may occur if you do not have proper access to read and/or delete a file or setting.

> And why is there an plist that stores all my information even my keyboard model. `co.twopeople.mate.plist` contains even more information than `Apple Global Domain`

It's impossible to know, but you may consider reaching out the developers of that app, it's not something present on any of my machines, so it was likely installed by a 3rd party program that you used in the past.

Comment: This is excellent. TLDR the file don’t mean anything, it’s the database that `defaults` reads and writes that stores the values now.

Comment: I’m very interested in exploring this more @bmike which database file would this use?  I’m assuming it’s a SQLite database.

Comment: cfprefsd provides preferences services for the CFPreferences and NSUserDefaults APIs. @DougMasters

Answer (score 1):

permissions can prevent access by defaults command. Be sure that the user is owner of the plist file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I used an MDM to update /Users/xxx/Library/Preferences plist file and the permissions were then altered, so I had to add additional code to reset permissions back to original owner and this prevented the "file does not exist" error when the file actually existed.